# Changing from single-window X11 to unified Mac Window Manager

Tags: mac, xorg

At some point I configured X11 to be fullscreen on my Mac.  Unfortunately, X11 on the Mac is hideous in fullscreen.  There are drawing problems, where the menus aren't completely drawn for example, and the screen is constantly refreshing to redraw the entire screen.  How can I get back to use the original version where X11 is integrated with the Mac OS apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once in X11, try <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.

Then, go to the X11 Preferences via the menu, and in the 'Output' pane, uncheck 'Full-screen Mode'

[image: X11 Preferences]

Comment: This gets me to fullscreen mode.  X still has a problem drawing the menus, for example. :-(

Comment: Hmm...I have a feeling X11-based programs are in general going to have poor Look&Feel compared to native Cocoa apps.  However, I think I misunderstood your question; if you have 10.6 keep an eye out for 2.4.1 of XQuartz @ http://xquartz.macosforge.org/trac/wiki  If you have anything older than Snow Leopard, try installing XQuartz

Comment: ok.  I do have SnowLeopard.  Didn't realize there was better X11 support with XQuartz.  Will watch for 2.4.1.  Thanks.